# update salary by 10% by number of dependents oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

So I want to update the salaries of the employees by 10% by each dependent they have. So id an employee is mentioned thrice in the dependent table, his salary is 100, his updated salary will be 100*1.10*1.10*1.10 which is 133.1. Here is the employee table

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    ENumber     CHAR(5)         NOT NULL, /* Employee number        */
    Salary      DECIMAL(7,2),             /* Salary         */
    CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY(ENumber)
);
```

and here is the dependent table

```
CREATE TABLE Dependent (
    ENumber     CHAR(5)         NOT NULL, /* Employee number        */
    DName       VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL, /* Dependent name     */
    CONSTRAINT Dependent_PK PRIMARY KEY(ENumber, DName),
    CONSTRAINT Dependent_FK FOREIGN KEY(ENumber) REFERENCES Employee(ENumber)
);
```

I am able to update their salaries but only once by 10%, and it is done regardless of how many dependents they have. This is what I have till now

```
update employee set salary=salary*1.10 where enumber in (select enumber from dependent);
```

Comment: i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted example data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE Employee e
SET Salary = Salary * POWER(1.1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dependent WHERE ENumber = e.ENumber));
```

This:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dependent WHERE ENumber = e.ENumber
```

returns a number say `p` of dependents of the employee, 
so you need to raise `1.1` to the power of `p` and multiply by `salary`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is taking the rows in the original salary table and updating them if they have any dependents, not based on the number of dependents.

```
UPDATE e SET e.salary=e.salary*POWER(1.10,d.DCount)
FROM employee e
JOIN (SELECT ENumber, COUNT(1) AS DCount FROM dependent GROUP BY ENumber) d
ON e.enumber = d.enumber
```